# append dictionaries from csv file

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The following code applies one update to my project.

```
tagPath = ["Package_PLC/Tags/CCN_CNV01_MX001_A_FLT"]
alarmConfig = {"BLD_CHN01_VS001_A_FLT_C":[["enabled","Value","0"]]}
system.tag.editAlarmConfig(tagPaths, alarmConfig)
```

I need to do this hundreds of times.

I am trying to build `tagPath` and `alarmConfig` dictionaries from a csv file.

Sample csv:

```
Equipment,Item Name,Alarm Tag,Alarm Name,Cluster Name,Category,Alarm Desc,Delay,Help,Comment,Variable Tag A,Variable Tag B,Custom 1,Custom 2,Custom 3,Custom 4,Custom 5,Custom 6,Custom 7,Custom 8,Paging,Paging Group,Area,Privilege,Historize,Project,SEQUENCE,TAGGENLINK,EDITCODE,LINKED
"","","BLD_CHN01_VS001_A_FLT_C","BLD_CHN01_VS001_A_FLT_C","","","Catch-up Conveyor / Chain Comms Fault","00:00:00","","BLD_CHN01_VS001_A_FLT_C","BLD_CHN01_VS001_A_FLT_C","KFS_ZNE02_WRM","STUN","","","","","","","","","","1","","","","","","",""
"","","BLD_CHN01_VS001_A_FLT_V","BLD_CHN01_VS001_A_FLT_V","","","Catch-up Conveyor / Chain VSD Fault","00:00:00","","BLD_CHN01_VS001_A_FLT_V","BLD_CHN01_VS001_A_FLT_V","","STUN","","","","","","","","","","1","","","","","","",""
"","","BLD_CHN01_VS001_S_HTY","BLD_CHN01_VS001_S_HTY","","","Catch-up Conveyor / Chain Cicuit Breaker","00:00:00","","BLD_CHN01_VS001_S_HTY","NOT BLD_CHN01_VS001_S_HTY","KFS_ZNE02_WRM","STUN","","","","","","","","","","1","","","","","","",""
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import system
import csv

path = system.file.openFile('csv')
if path != None:
    print "path found"
    f=open(path)
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    path1 = "Package_PLC/Tags/"
    tagpath = []
    alarmConfig = []
    state = 0
    comment = ""

    for i in reader:

        if row['Alarm Tag'] == 'ECN*' || 'FCN*' || 'PAC*':
            tagpath.append(path1 + int(row['Alarm Tag']))
            alarmname = row[Alarm Tag]

            if row[Variable Tag A] == "NOT*":
                state = 0
            else:
                state = 1

            comment = row[Alarm Desc]
            alarmConfig.append({alarmname: [["setpointA","Value",state],      
                                            ["displayPath","Value","Packing"],
                                            ["notes","Value",comment]]        
                               })                                             
            system.tag.editAlarmConfig(tagPaths, alarmConfig)

    f.close()
```

The following error gets thrown.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<buffer>", line 28, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers
```

Comment: Not related to the problem, but `row['Alarm Tag'] == 'ECN*' || 'FCN*' || 'PAC*':` should be `row['Alarm Tag'] in ('ECN*', 'FCN*', 'PAC*')`

Comment: Which line is getting the error?

Comment: You're missing lots of quotes.

Comment: You should get an error on this: `path1 + int(row['Alarm Tag'])`. You can't add a string and an integer.

Comment: Is `i` supposed to be `row`?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I strongly suggest you indent your code with space character instead of tabs. You can probably configure your editor to automatically turn the latter into the former when you type it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
import string
import system
import csv

path = system.file.openFile('csv')
if path != None:
    print "path found"
    f=open(path)
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)  

    path1 = "Package_PLC/Tags/"
    tagpath = []
    alarmConfig = {}
    state = 0
    readerlist = list(reader)

    for stuff in readerlist:
        if "PAC" in stuff['Alarm Tag'] or "ECN" in stuff['Alarm Tag'] or "CCN" in stuff['Alarm Tag'] or "FCN" in stuff['Alarm Tag'] :
            tagpath = []
            tagpath.append(str( path1 + stuff['Alarm Tag']))

            if "NOT" in stuff['Variable Tag A']:
                state = 0
            else :
                state = 1

            display = ['displayPath','Value','Packing']

            notes = ['notes','Value',str(stuff['Alarm Desc'])]

            setpointA =['setpointA','Value', str(state)]

            alarmConfig = {}

            alarmConfig[stuff['Alarm Tag']] = [display,notes,setpointA]

            system.tag.editAlarmConfig(tagpath, alarmConfig)

    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to help you because:

- The sample file doesn't trigger anything
- You didn't provide the `system` module

But still here's my attempt:

```py
import os.path
import csv

input_file_name = 'Sample.csv'

if os.path.exists(input_file_name):
    with open(input_file_name, newline='') as input_file:
        events = csv.DictReader(input_file)
        data_extracted = [
            (
                current_event['Alarm Tag'], 
                0 if current_event['Variable Tag A'].startswith('NOT') else 1,
                current_event['Alarm Desc']
            )
            for current_event in events
            if current_event['Alarm Tag'][:3] in ('ECN', 'FCN', 'PAC')
        ]

    tag_paths = [f'Package_PLC/Tags/{x[0]}' for x in data_extracted]
    alarm_config = {
        alarm_name: [
            ['setpointA', 'Value', state],
            ['displayPath', 'Value', 'Packing'],
            ['notes', 'value', comment]
        ]
        for (alarm_name, state, comment) in data_extracted
    }
    system.tag.editAlarmConfig(tag_paths, alarm_config)
```